# Properly configuring Oracle Charset and NLS parameters

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, oracle-12c, character-set, nls

I'm trying to figure out the reason why Oracle SQL Developer shows question marks/rubbish on non-latin symbols. Currently I have 2 DBs on separate severs/instances, one of which works fine, and the other one breaks encoding as written above. Both were checked with same SQL Developer with same environment WITHOUT NLS_LANG set.

Here are NLS* tables for each case:

Normal)

`select * from nls_database_parameters;
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET    CL8MSWIN1251
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   10.2.0.3.0`

`select * from nls_instance_parameters;
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_SORT

NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE

NLS_DATE_FORMAT 
NLS_CURRENCY

NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS

NLS_ISO_CURRENCY

NLS_CALENDAR

NLS_TIME_FORMAT 
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT

NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT

NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT 
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY

NLS_COMP

NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE`

Strange)

`select * from nls_database_parameters;
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   12.1.0.2.0
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET    CL8MSWIN1251
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN`



`select * from nls_instance_parameters;
NLS_LANGUAGE    RUSSIAN
NLS_TERRITORY   RUSSIA
NLS_SORT

NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE

NLS_DATE_FORMAT 
NLS_CURRENCY

NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS

NLS_ISO_CURRENCY

NLS_CALENDAR

NLS_TIME_FORMAT 
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT

NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT

NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT 
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY

NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE`

Session params)

`select * from nls_session_parameters;
NLS_LANGUAGE    ENGLISH
NLS_TERRITORY   UNITED KINGDOM
NLS_CURRENCY    ?
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    UNITED KINGDOM
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   ENGLISH
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   €
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE`

Changing strange's instance NLS-params didn't do the trick. Data integrity is verified - a webapp that connects to this DB works fine if NLS_LANG is explicitly set to RUSSIAN_RUSSIA.CL8MSWIN1251. I just can't figure out why FIRST database works fine as is and the SECOND has to be explicitly configured client-side, even if I change instance settings. What am I missing?